# "Any club cannot use . . ." vs. "No club can use . . ."

Tags: grammar, expressions, negation

Here in Japan, many of my students use "any" in a negative sentence like this:

> "Please note that any club/group cannot use the copy machine after 8:00pm."

I believe this is grammatically incorrect, or at least unnatural and should be:

> "Please note that no club/group can use the copy machine after 8:00pm."

My question(s) is/are:

- Is the first sentence grammatically incorrect or is it just a matter of natural style?
- In the case that it is grammatically incorrect, what is the rule regarding such a sentence construction? (Any . . .cannot  vs  No.....can)

I would like  to give them a reason for changing their work beyond "It's just a native-English thing".

Thank you very much for your help on this.

GT in Japan

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  But the key point is why is it incorrect? I have to give them a reason for changing their work beyond "It's just a native-English thing. . ."

Comment: Allowing clubs not to use the copy machine after 8 pm (I'm sure they're grateful, it must be exhausting coming in every night) is not the same thing is not allowing them to use it.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct. *Any ... cannot* sounds very wrong in my ears

You can however use this construct:

> Please note that the copy machine cannot be used by any club/group after 8:00pm.

or

> Please note that after 8:00pm, the copy machine cannot be used by any club/group

I apologise that I *cannot* find *any* rules you can use to explain this to them.

Perhaps *someone* else can

Answer (score 2):

The nearest I can get to any kind of rule derives from the distinction made in the ‘Longman Student Grammar of Spoken and Written English’ between ‘assertive’ forms such as *some* and non-assertive forms such as *any*. The authors write that ‘non-assertive forms follow the *not*'. This would allow the passive construction:

> The copy machine cannot be used by any group after 8:00pm.

but would not allow the active construction in your example, where *any* precedes *(can)not*.

This explanation might need testing. A single counter-example would undermine it.

Comment: That's the same as I posted, no?

Comment: @mplungjan No, this answer quotes a source giving a rule.

Comment: I meant the resulting sentence

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Further to my earlier example, note that the positive version of the statement has no problem:  "Please note that any club/group can use the copy machine after 8:00pm."  I am stumped on this....