# Any proposition...cannot be... vs. No proposition...can be

Tags: negation

In [another post](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/182695/27275), Lord Esher was quoted as saying this sentence:

> **Any** proposition the result of which would be to show that the common law of England is wholly unreasonable and unjust **cannot** be part of the common law of England.
> (Boldface mine.)

I wonder if this construction "**Any** proposition... **cannot** be..." is natural in Present-day English (PDE). Shouldn't it have the construction "**No** proposition... **can** be..." as follows?

> **No** proposition the result of which would be to show that the common law of England is wholly unreasonable and unjust **can** be part of the common law of England.

If it's not natural in PDE, was it natural when Lord Esher uttered this sentence? If so, when exactly was it?

### EDIT

There seem to be at least a couple of prior questions questioning the validity of the *Any...not* construction:

(1) ["Any club cannot use . . ." vs. "No club can use . . ."](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/126172/27275), where @BarrieEngland cited ‘Longman Student Grammar of Spoken and Written English’ as showing a rule against the first construction.

(2) [Why can't "any" be used as subject in negative sentences, while "no" can?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/590963/27275), asking why *Any children didn't come* doesn't work whereas *No children came* does. Here, @JohnLawler basically proposes a test to see if removing "not" would render the sentence ungrammatical.

I have yet to figure out, though, whether and how these prior answers would help resolve the issue at hand.

For example, in (1)'s example *Please note that any club **cannot** use the copy machine after 8:00pm*, removing ***not*** doesn't render it ungrammatical: *Please note that any club **can** use the copy machine after 8:00pm*, which means, according to @JohnLawler's answer in (2), that (1)'s example is grammatical as is, which is not in line with @BarrieEngland's answer there.

Comment: You ask if the expression is natural. You seen. to be a native speaker; if you’re also in an English-speaking community, you should have some insight - . om whether i

Comment: seen.=seem (4 more to go it says).

Comment: Both of those formulations have the same logical structure: `¬ (∃x: P(x)) Q(x))`, that is, there is no _x_ with the property _P_ such that _x_ has the property _Q_. This can be expressed in English in a number of ways, and the propositions given are two of them.

Comment: Why would you consider it unnatural? In what respect?

Comment: @alphabet I'm not saying it's unnatural but only asking if it's natural.

Comment: @Greybeard The relative clause is _the result of which would be to show that the common law of England is wholly unreasonable and unjust_, which combines with _proposition_ to form a nominal (N'), and then this N' combines with _Any_ to form the subject NP. In the subject NP, the head is _proposition_, not _result_, so I don't understand how it means "the result cannot be...".

Comment: You are right; I was wrong. I've removed my comment and looked at it again. The principle can be demonstrated as {Any dog, the puppies of which are brown} cannot be the father of black puppies. ->
A specified dog cannot be the father of black puppies.

Comment: Your intuition about PDE is correct. The "any/cannot" version would be odd (though not unacceptable); today we're more likely to use the "no/can" version. However, I don't know whether or not it was more common in Lord Esher's day.

Comment: @JK2 Further to alphabet's Comment, I for two see the wording you used as much more clearly suggesting a belief posing as a query…

Comment: What are you really Asking? Whether either example is grammatically correct? To me, both seem to be. Whether the negative and positive versions boil down to the same thing? To me, they seem to. Something else? What might that be?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin Please see the EDIT.

Comment: Would it seem more natural if we shortened the modifier of "proposition" by replacing it with a pro-form: "Any such proposition cannot be part of the common law of England."

Comment: While I don't recall the original wording, that Edit seems largely to want to compare 'Any club cannot…' to 'No club can…' but how is that legitimate? I see Joel as rather generous with ' "any/cannot" would be odd (though not unacceptable)'. I think today we're not merely 'more likely' but in fact virtually guaranteed to use 'no/can', and 'any/cannot' is so archaic it's more likely to be confusing than distinctive or stylish.

Your ellipses hide the fact it's moving away from, not towards 'Any proposition… cannot be…'.

More…

Comment: Further…

The late-coming 'Any club cannot…' in the Edit almost means something by itself.

The earlier 'Any proposition... cannot...' is by itself dangerously misleading. Far from providing a reasonable contraction, the chosen ellipses mask the meaning of the original 'Any proposition the result of which (blah lah la)…'

Which boils down to comparing 'any thing…' to 'any thing which…'

How is that reasonable?

Sorry I left out huge swathes of technical vocabulary.

Comment: By the way, given the development in these Comments, wouldn't this Question have been better Posted in, for instance, SE Writing or English Language Learners?

Comment: If I knew how to do it, I'd recommend closing the topic and moving Comments to Chat.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan Would it seem less natural if we removed the modifier of "proposition": "Any proposition cannot be part of the common law of England."

Comment: @JK2 That's a good question, although that version alters the meaning of the original. But yes, I think that both versions could be useful to consider when weighing this question.